# How to force an element to be in array form (in php)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have code that iterates over an array of elements which are themselves arrays. The code works fine for 2 or more such elements. However, it does NOT work for ONE array "element" (because it starts to iterate over each of its sub elements).

my code:

```
  foreach($list as $element)
  ...
```

most of the time, $list is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'abc'
            [b] => 'bcd'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'abc'
            [b] => 'bcd'
        )
)
```

ehich works fine, but if $list is:

```
 Array
 (
    [a] => 'abc'
    [b] => 'bcd'
  )
```

obviously my code would now screw up as foreach would iterate through 'a' and 'b'.

I want to convert:

```
 Array
 (
    [a] => 'abc'
    [b] => 'bcd'
  )
```

into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 'abc'
            [b] => 'bcd'
        )
 )
```

in the most efficient way possible!

Comment: I really didn't get the question, but have you tried the is_array() function instead...?

Comment: yup - that would fail as well... lemme try explaining again - sorry for not being clear (see main question)

Comment: @Treffynnon @MEsch @Nemoden - please hava look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up checking the individual element, if a specific one (known to exist only WITHIN the array of arrays) existed at the bottom level, then did something like:

```
 $list = Array 
  ( 
    [0] => $list
  ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`is_array()` (linked)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to detect whether the passed item is an array or not. You can then handle it accordingly.

```
foreach($somethingarray['something'] as $something) {
    if(is_array($something)) {
        // do something with array
    } else {
        // do something with non array
    }
}
```

Run this on http://www.phplint.com/ to see the result addressing your comments @Frank D.

```
echo '<pre>';
$var = array( 'my_var' => array( 'my_value' ) );
var_dump( $var );
$var2 = array( $var );
var_dump( $var2 );
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: umm - think of it as i want foreach to work with array(a,b) and with c as well

Comment: Yeah I know and understand what your question was. The code above is the right way to handle it. If you want to ensure you will always get an array then try putting `$something = array($something)` in the else clause above.

Comment: doesnt work if that something is itself alreayd an array... @Treffynnon

Comment: @Frank D Have you even tried it? It does work. This is starting to bore me now. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use (array) to force your variable to be an array like so:

```
foreach ((array)$somethingarray['something'] as $something) { /* $something is first array's element... And the only if you casted your "not-array" into an array by (array) */ }
```

Comment: i dont think that would work if $somethingarray['something']  was Array (    [a] => 'abc' )

Comment: So, why it works even after you said it does not? :) http://dpaste.com/hold/531853/ I'm just curious, did you even try before you made a statement?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/531855/ - In this case $arr['something'] is array([a] => 'abc'). **Exactly** like you said.

Comment: @Nemoden - thanks for your post (and pastebin reference), but that's not what i need. Please see the clarified explanation above

Answer (score 0):

As you know, foreach will iterate over each element in an array.  If an array is empty, it won't do anything.  So you could simply do $var = array (); to set an empty array.

A better solution is to check before executing your foreach statements whether the input is an array, using in_array().

Comment: it is supposed to handle arrays, an "array" OF arrays...! :)

Answer (score 0):

be careful how do you insert your first element
never let $list be

```
Array
(
   [a] => 'abc'
   [b] => 'bcd'
)
```

so

```
//create your first element as
$firstElement=array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'bcd');
$list[] = $firstElement;                 
// or in one sentence:  $list[] = array('a'=>'abc', 'b'=>'bcd');
// call your function here for one elment array
yourFunc($list)

// and so on the same way (how did you made the two elements $list array?)
$secondElement = array('a'=>'abc', 'b'=>'bcd');
$list[] = $secondElement;
// call your function here for two elments array
yourFunc($list)
```